# mysql JOIN between three tables

Tags: mysql, join, nested

I have 4 tables in my database:

```
users (id,name)
roles (id,name)
positions (id,name)
position_user (user_id,position_id)
```

- Relationship between users to roles is one to one
- Relationship between users positions is many to many

i want to take all users with their role name and list with their positions but i don't know how to structure my query. I think that one of my query must be something like this:

```
SELECT pu.user_id AS user_id, 
       group_concat(p.name separator ',') AS list_pos
FROM position_user pu 
INNER JOIN positions p 
        ON p.id = pu.position_id 
GROUP BY pu.user_id
```

And other one must be like this :

```
SELECT users.id, users.first_name, roles.name
FROM users
JOIN roles 
  ON users.role_id = roles.id
```

Can I combine these two in one query and how ?

Comment: Show us sample data and desire output.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this and check the MySQL documentation.

```
SELECT pu.user_id AS user_id, u.first_name, r.name as rol_name, group_concat(p.name separator ',') AS list_pos
    FROM position_user pu 
    INNER JOIN positions p ON p.id = pu.position_id 
    INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = pu.uder_id
    INNER JOIN roles R ON u.role_id = r.id
    GROUP BY pu.user_id, u.first_name, r.name
```